# Proof of this equality in "Bayesian prediction"

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability

$p(y|x,S) = \int_{\theta}p(y|x,\theta)p(\theta|S)d\theta$

Is this formula correct in general or just in bayesian settings?  How do I prove it?

Note: this formula comes from stanford cs229 course lecture notes. Page 7, formula(2) from http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes5.pdf

Comment: You get the conditional marginal density by integrating out the conditional joint density $p(y,\theta\mid S)$ over $\theta$. This is not confined to Bayesian inference.

Comment: @Student $p(y|S) = \int_{\theta}p(y,\theta|S)d\theta = \int_{\theta}p(y|\theta,S)p(\theta|S)$. Still needs to prove $p(y|\theta,S)=p(y|\theta)$. Can you clarify on this?

Answer (score 0):

The set-up is that $S$ are the data, $x$ is the conditional value, and you are trying to predict the posterior density of $y$.

What is happening is that there is some "deep parameter" $\theta$ about which you have a posterior based on data, $p[\theta|S]$.  But you do not know $\theta$, you only have beliefs about what it might be.  However, if you knew $\theta$ and $x$, it would be sufficient to predict the density of $y$, given by $p[y|x,\theta]$.

So to overcome this lack of information, you're going to integrate over all possible values of $\theta$, weighting the "true" density of $y$ given $x$ and $\theta$ by the probability you think a given $\theta$ is true.

So your prediction of $y$ conditional on the data $S$, for a given $x$ in which you are interested, is
$$
\underbrace{p[y|x,S]}_{\text{Density of $y$ conditional on $x$, given data $S$}} = \int_\theta \underbrace{p[y|x,\theta]}_{\text{True relationship between $y$, $x$, $\theta$}} \quad \underbrace{p[\theta|S]}_{\text{Probablility $\theta$ is true given the data}} d\theta
$$

So you are integrating out your uncertainty over $\theta$ using your data-based beliefs.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I understand the meaning of the formula in the Bayesian settings. However, I am having difficulty proving this particular formula in a rigorous mathematical way. My intuition tells me the formula is true in general but I just can't prove it.

Comment: There is a big assumption: $p[y|x,\theta]$ is "true".  Without that, none of it would make sense.  In particular, $p[y|x,\theta] = p[y|x,\theta,S]$ is being assumed, so that the realization of the data do not affect future realizations of $y$.  In that sense, there is a latent assumption that realizations of the process are i.i.d.; for example if $y$ was a Markov chain, recent realizations would affect future ones.